# Webpack determine asset entry

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

Working on a plugin to take specific asset types and consolidated them down to a single file.
I would like to be able to consolidate assets down into files based on which entry brought them in.

```
entry.one.js
 - asset a
 - asset b

entry.two.js
 - asset c
 - asset d
```

Desired result is one file having a/b assets, another file having c/d assets.

Is there a way to determine which entry an asset came from?

It appears that Webpack's `compilation.processAssets` and `compliation.getAsset()` don't really give you much context into what entry brought what asset in.

```js
  compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap(
    {
      name: 'BobRoss',
      stage: compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ANALYSE,
      additionalAssets: true
    },
    (assets) => {
      for (let i in assets) {
        console.log(assets[i]);
        console.log(compilation.getAsset(i));
      }
    }
  )
```

Do I need to look at assets from another hook location? Maybe from chunks, or modules to determine this?
Any direction would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
`compilation.chunkAsset.tap()` is the hook in question where you can both gather a chunk's assets, but also determine if that chunk came from one entry or another:

```js
const entries = compiler.options.entry;

// Hook into compilation
compiler.hooks.compilation.tap({ name: 'BobRoss' }, (compilation) => {

  // Hook into chunkAsset
  compilation.hooks.chunkAsset.tap('BobRoss', (chunk, filename) => {

    // Only process chunks that are entry files
    if (entries[path.basename(filename)]) {  

      // get chunk's asset paths.
      const paths = [...chunk.auxiliaryFiles]; 

      // resolve paths into asset objects using compilation.getAsset()
      entries[path.basename(filename)].assets = Object.keys(paths).map((n) => compilation.getAsset(assets[n]));

    }
  });

});
```

Will result in `entries` object now looking like:

```json
[{
  entry.one: {
    import: ['path/to/entry/file/entry.one.js'],
    assets: [asset, asset]
  }
},{
  entry.two: {
    import: ['path/to/entry/file/entry.one.js'],
    assets: [asset, asset]
  }
}]
```

From here, the processes of consolidating and adding these to the build as two new assets is trivial under the `compilation.processAssets` Webpack hook.